# Is it possible to create a custom view to display search results?

Tags: support, search

After reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching help I have set up a custom search to find questions that interest me.

Here is an example of my custom search url https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5Danswers%3A..0+created%3A2014

When I look over questions, I would like to be able to know how much activity has already happened on it, for example comments, number of views and number of revisions(edits).

Is it possible to set up a custom view to display that information? In the similar matter, how I can see when just coming to https://stackoverflow.com/ it shows Votes, Answers, Views. So is there a way to do it with what already is built into site, or do I have to use an external tool?

Comment: You could rig up a SEDE query for it... give me a minute.

Comment: can someone clarify what is wrong with my question to get negative votes?

Comment: @SaUce: I do not like begging people for downvote reasons, but I do not see anything wrong about your question. I just gave a +1. I think it is unfortunately a general attitude on meta. Also, downvote may mean disagreement rather than bad question. Just move on.